# Is it possible to synchronize ConcurrentHashMap update by it's key?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have tons of update operation on ConcurrentHashMap and I need to minimize synchronization for update this map.

please see code below.

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> dataMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void updateData(String key, int data) {
        if ( dataMap.containsKey(key)) {
            // do something with previous value and new value and update it
        }
    }
```

For example, When one thread calls `updateData` with Key "A", then every other try calling `updateData` with key "A" should be blocked until first thread is done.  meanwhile, I want another thread trying to call `updateData` with key "B" runs concurrently.

I wonder if there is any fancy way to lock hashMap simply with its key.

Comment: Is there any issue without synchronization? I guess the `put` operation of ConcurrentHashMap internally uses `synchronization` over the segment. You don't have to do it explicitly

Comment: If you use `computeIfPresent`, the synchronization is over single keys iiuc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [`compute` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

It takes a function that is given the key and the current value (or `null` if there is no value yet), and can compute the new value.

ConcurrentHashMap guarantees that only one such functions runs at the same time for the given key. A concurrent second call will block until ready.